# Congressional Record in electronic form

Tags: data-request, usa, government, historical, legal

Is there a way to get an electronic copy of the Congressional Record, or otherwise get information about all the speakers in Congress, what they said, when they said, the votes on all motions bills, the text of all bills and related information?

I was unable to find the Congressional Record going back more that 20 years or so, but I imagine that since it is printed, it must be available somewhere.

Anyone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 5):

The Sunlight Foundation makes a lot of Congressional Record data available through its [Capitol Words](http://capitolwords.org/) API:

http://capitolwords.org/api/1/

It's focused on speeches, and doesn't bring much order to chaos beyond that.

But you're also looking for votes, and bills, and bill text? Rather than plumb the depths of the Congressional Record, you can get that from this project:

https://github.com/unitedstates/congress

Which has various scrapers that assemble this from around Congress. This is the data that ends up in [GovTrack](https://www.govtrack.us) and in the Sunlight Foundation's [Congress API](http://sunlightlabs.github.io/congress).

Comment: How far does the data go back?

Comment: Depends on the data set. Speeches back to 1989, votes back to the early 90's, bill text back to the early 90's, and other bill metadata back to the 1970's.

Answer (score 4):

I would checkout govtrack.us. They make their datasets available as 'public domain'.

https://www.govtrack.us/developers

*Any data files we make available from the Source Data page for which we own the copyright we release into the public domain.*

Comment: This is only very recent data. Is there anywhere that has older data?

Comment: They have been collecting data since 2004. Checkout their API how to get historical data (https://www.govtrack.us/developers/api). For example, here is all bills from the 110th congress: http://www.govtrack.us/api/v2/bill?congress=110

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about electronic copy of congressional record, but what they said and the votes on all motions bills and other information can be easily be query using this online application [iknow.io](http://iknow.io/) - you can try the [data navigator](http://iknow.io/explore/uscongress-2/navigator/) to query congressman name.

FYI - They are using govetrack.us, but they are doing all heavy lifting so that any one can query information easily.

Comment: What is "those?"

Comment: Updated. I am not pro on the subject, but you can query about  candidate's contribution, bill sponsored, votes etc. Though it might be good source.